# Load a div on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I am using ASP.NET MVC telerik control to post an AJAX call to reload a page.
But i only want to partially load a div within a page. How can i do that?

```
$('#AddInventory').ajaxForm({
beforeSubmit: function () {

    showWaitSlider("Please wait while uploading files. This may take a few moments.");
    return true;
},
success: function (data) {
    hideWaitSlider();
    location.reload();


},
error: function (xhr, status, err) {
    hideWaitSlider();
    alert(xhr.responseText);
},
dataType: 'json'
```

});

Comment: 3 upvotes man still not acceptable.....??? :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` in the success function should return the response HTML, which you can parse to get your div.

```
//location.reload();
$("#MyDiv").html($("#MyDiv", data).html);
```